# Eu posso escrever "sistema brasileiro de eleições" ao invés de "sistema eleitoral brasileiro" em uma redação ou artigo?

Tags: gramática

Esse termo não existe ou é considerado errado?

Answer (score 7):

Uma das características que distinguem um falante nativo de um não-nativo fluente, é justamente o fato de que este último consegue falar e escrever corretamente mas por vezes diz ou escreve algo que não é idiomático. E a tua pergunta presta-se bem a isso, a mostrar a diferença entre o que é correto e idiomático e aquilo que embora correto, não é idiomático.

- "sistema eleitoral brasileiro" é correto e idiomático. É o que se ouve o tempo todo.
- "sistema de eleições brasileiro" ou "sistema brasileiro de eleições" são ambos gramaticalmente corretos, mas não são idiomáticos. No entanto são compreendidos perfeitamente.

Comment: Claro, sistema de eleições brasileiro soa horrivel mesmo. Parece estrangeirismo.

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim. Como o "sistema eleitoral brasileiro" não é um nome próprio, então a única coisa que importa é se fazer entendido. Poderia ser, também, sistema de eleições brasileiro, sistema de votação brasileiro, sistema brasileiro de votação e por aí vai.

Comment: Hm, o sistema eleitoral não é a mesma coisa que o sistema de votação.

Comment: Bom, para mim e segundo a Wikipedia "sistema de votação ou sistema eleitoral é o meio de escolha entre um certo número de opções, baseado na entrada de um certo número de votos."

Comment: sistema de votação é o meio usado para se totalizar os votos, como as urnas eletrônicas, ou contagem de votos; o que difere do sistema eleitoral que diz respeito a partidos, chapas, tipos de políticos, eleições, etc.